# Find the count of matching elements in R

Tags: r

sorry for the noob question ! I am trying to calculate the number of elements that matched in basket x with basket y.
I have the following data:

```
user_id basket.x basket.y
1         1,2,3    2,3,4
2         5,6,7    1,2,7
```

I have tried the following loop, but it doesnot work

```
df["total"] <- 0
df["TP"] <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
 for(j in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(all(df$basket.x[i] %in% df$basket.y[j])){
     df$total <- total + 1
     df$TP <- TP + 1
  }
 }
}
```

And returns this:

```
user_id basket.x basket.y   total TP
1         1,2,3    2,3,4     0    0
2         5,6,7    1,2,7     0    0
```

However, the desired result is:

```
user_id basket.x basket.y   total TP
1         1,2,3    2,3,4     3    2
2         5,6,7    1,2,7     3    1
```

Could anyone point me please where i am made mistake ?
Thank you

Running the dput() :

```
structure(list(user_id = c(2957L, 7306L, 10219L, 11290L, 13222L, 
13554L), basket.x = c("13870,22963,1158,18362"),basket.y = 
c("24852,432,47626,33647,6015,1158,24852,24852,24852")
), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is the type of `basket.x` and `basket.y`? They look like character strings or perhaps factors, in which case they would need to be parsed. In any event, could you please give a *reproducible* example? Use `dput(head(df))` where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: Also, you are looping through the rows twice, but I think you mean to match x with y only within a row - not basket x row 1 with basket y row 2.

Comment: Hi @JohnColeman, thank you for a reply, they are character, I have run the dput, you should be able to see it in the post now.

Comment: Hi @G5W, yeah i want to match x with y only within a row

Comment: When I use the result of your `dput` I get a "corrupt data frame" warning, which doesn't sound very promising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by @JohnColeman,  there is something wrong with your `dput` so I am using a combination of that and your original example.

```
df = structure(list(user_id = c(2957L, 7306L, 10219L), 
basket.x = c("13870,22963,1158,18362", "1,2,3", "5,6,7"),
basket.y = c("24852,432,47626,33647,6015,1158,24852,24852,24852",
"2,3,4", "1,2,7")
), row.names = c(1L,2L,3L), class = "data.frame")
df
  user_id               basket.x
1    2957 13870,22963,1158,18362
2    7306                  1,2,3
3   10219                  5,6,7
                                           basket.y
1 24852,432,47626,33647,6015,1158,24852,24852,24852
2                                             2,3,4
3                                             1,2,7
```

Using this data,  we can get the individual elements of the lists using `strsplit`. Once we have the elements, we can use `intersect` to find the elements that are in both `basket.x` and `basket.y`. To get how many elements the two baskets share, we can just take the length of the intersection. Of course,  we need to apply this across all of the rows of `df`.   Putting this together, we get

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) 
    length(intersect(strsplit(df$basket.x, ",")[[i]],
            strsplit(df$basket.y, ",")[[i]])))
[1] 1 2 1
```

**Edit**
Thanks to @thelatemail for noticing that the way I wrote this is very inefficient. Better is:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) 
    length(intersect(unlist(strsplit(df$basket.x[[i]], ",")),
            unlist(strsplit(df$basket.y[[i]], ",")))))
```

Comment: I think you want to move that `[[i]]` subsetting inside the `strsplit` - like `df$basket.x[i]` - or else you're doing the entire vector of `baskey.x/y` splitting *every* loop.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @G5W's answer would be possible through `Map` to replace (well, hide) the loop over each row index:

```
spl <- unname(lapply(df[-1], strsplit, ","))
lengths(do.call(Map, c(intersect, spl)))
#[1] 1 2 1
```

Although you have to save the intermediate `spl`, this should be significantly faster if you're dealing with larger datasets.